# Is it okay to edit questions into being "more canonical"?

Tags: discussion, questions

**Note to close voters:** My question is not a duplicate. The current duplicate target is asking ***how*** questions can be edited to become more canonical. I, on the other hand, am asking if that's even okay. **I'm asking whether or not I can edit a question to be better for a wider audience**, not how can I accomplish that.

---

I came across a question which was pretty popular. The question asker was asking about a basic, yet very common question regarding Python. The problem however, is that the OP uses fairly uncommon terminology in his title and question. This means that probably not many people would find the question, although the question itself is a very common one among beginners. I figured it would be more popular if the question was edited to use common terms.

Could I edit the question? I'm pretty sure I could edit the title just fine, but there are some lines in the original question I would have to change as well to make sense with the title and use the common terms. But this seems like it could be somewhat conflicting with the OP's intent.

In short: **Would it be wrong if I edited the original askers question to be more canonical?**

Comment: Such posters have to be quite cunning and resourceful in their choice of title, else the questions will be automatically recognised as a dup before their homework answer is copy/pasted out :)

Comment: Look at the view count of the question.  If it has *thousands* then there's something special going on, that only ever gets that high when Google lists it.  In other words, it is *because* it uses the wrong terminology, the kind that Google searchers use as well.  "Fixing" the question would then completely destroy its usefulness.  Don't do that.

Comment: "fairly uncommon terminology" may be the case to you, but for some (people who are not native speakers or even who's brains work in a slightly different way for example), that terminology may be a pretty good representation of what they are asking. So, there may be occasions where it's useful to have the less common terminology left alone and linked as a duplicate to the more common version.

Comment: You say the question was `pretty popular` - how does that fit to `not many people would find the question`?

Comment: @baao Because I believe most of the questions popularity came from it being used a dup target so often. Not because it got lots of hits. That's how I found it. But I thought the question could be improved as a better dupe target my editing it. Hence my question.

Comment: @gnat See my edit. My question is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, it is absolutely okay to edit the *terminology* in a question, whether to make it more precise or more searchable.

This is one of the major reasons why we have community edits. Obviously, improving spelling and grammar is nice, but the major benefit here is when domain experts can tweak wording and clarify things. People who have questions about something are probably not experts in that thing, and it's not at all unusual that they get some things wrong.

Editing the title is best, because it's the least amount of work for you, and puts the fewest amount of words in the author's mouth, while having the highest impact. But, like you said, you might also need to tweak the body slightly so that the title makes sense.

If the answers refer directly to the terminology used in the question, then you should leave that terminology in place in the question body, *adding* the canonical phrasing *to it*, rather than replacing it outright. (It's fine to replace it completely in the title, since titles need to be short and punchy.)

Speaking more generally, I would say that it's also okay to edit a question and make it more canonical. But you have to be a bit careful with that. First and foremost, you need to respect the author's intent<sup>*</sup>. You also need to be mindful of the existing answers (if any) and make sure that you don't invalidate them. If you're making cosmetic changes, and the existing answers quote any of those lines from the question, then you may need to edit those quotations or some of the general language in the answers. Again, you need to do so with a light touch, respecting the authors' intent. Finally, when editing a question to make it more canonical, you need to make sure that you don't inadvertently make the question too broad.

__
<sub>* The exception to this, I believe, is when the question is completely unacceptable in its current/original form, and your edits are the only thing standing between its closure/deletion. Then, it's okay to deviate somewhat from the authors' original intent. If they really dislike your edits, they are free to roll them back and suffer the potential consequences. But, in most cases I've seen, this works out to the maximum benefit of all parties.</sub>

Comment: _"adding the canonical phrasing to it"_ - What exactly do you mean here? How exactly should I integrate the new terms into the question? Anything I'm currently think of would seem tacky or silly.

Comment: Umm, I'm not really sure. I'd have to see a specific question where I could speak in context. And Python isn't something I'm familiar with, so I'm not sure that my advice would be particularly helpful. Basically, though, you could do what any editor would do and put one of the terms in parentheses. Or maybe introduce a dependent clause where you explain its meaning.

Comment: Ah, OK. That's what I was looking for. An idea of what you meant.

Answer (score 6):

> The question asker was asking about a basic, yet very common question regarding Python.

This is a major red flag. Basic and common questions typically already have a question and answer on the site, especially if the technology is well established like Python. So step one is check for a dupe.

If you find one, *do not* edit the question's terminology. The value in duplicate questions is that [it can help funnel other people searching toward the answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/). It will be *less* effective at this job if you remove the unconventional terminology. If the view count is high (as Hans Passant [mentions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351645/is-it-okay-to-edit-questions-into-being-more-canonical/351669#comment487893_351645)), then people are already finding it by searching for the wrong terminology; an edit on such a question would be especially damaging.

If you cannot find a dupe, *then* it's okay to touch up the question's terminology. But I wouldn't go too far on that front. At some point, clarifying the terminology becomes part of the answer.

So,

1. Find a dupe.
2. Edit only if dupe cannot be found.

Comment: I understand I need to find a dupe, but the entire reason I want to edit this question is that it seems to be used a common dupe target.